Biggest ellipse that can fit in a lens
If I have a lens of radius $1$ and arc length $\theta$, what is the biggest ellipse that can cleanly fit inside it?
It is obvious that the minor axis will be $1-\cos\theta$, but what about the major axis? Just to be clear, by biggest I mean area.
Here's a nice desmos graph for this: graph

In order to fit inside the lens, the radius of curvature of the ellipse at the two points on the $x$-axis must be less than 1. The constraint will probably give you a solution.

It is not obvious at all that the minor axis will be as you said.

@BrianTung Yes. I see no reason to believe that the ellipse with the largest area that can fit inside the lens will be exactly as wide as the lens.

It is necessary to consider the case where the inscribed ellipse makes contact with the (biconvex) lens at four distinct points, rather than the two points on the common axis joining the centers of the circles.  There may be an advantage to sacrificing some of the ellipse's minor axis to gain area from a longer major axis.  This, I presume, is Ivan's point.

@IvanNeretin: Yes, thanks, just thought it would be good to clarify that. Unfortunately, I deleted my question comment without thinking, but I think your comment is clear enough on its own.

Here's a question related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5010712/1385195

In this question, there may be different interpretations about fitting:

Fitting a sample shape by identifying the order of contact at a particular point.
Inscribing an ellipse into the lens shape with maximal area.


I'll adopt the second case.

Circular arcs, $(0<h<R)$

$$(x \mp h)^2+y^2=R^2$$

Ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Intersection

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{R^2-(x\mp h)^2}{b^2}=1$$
$$
\left(
  \frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}
\right)x^2
\pm \frac{2hx}{b^2}+
\frac{R^2-h^2}{b^2}-1=0$$

For tangency, $\Delta=0$

$$\frac{4h^2}{b^4}=4
\left(
  \frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}
\right)
\left(
  \frac{R^2-h^2}{b^2}-1
\right)$$
$$a=b\sqrt{\frac{R^2-h^2-b^2}{R^2-b^2}}$$

Area

$$A=\pi a b$$

Extremum

$$\frac{dA}{db}=0$$
$$2b^4+b^2(h^2-4R^2)+2R^2(R^2-h^2)=0$$
$$b=\frac{\sqrt{4R^2-h^2-h\sqrt{8R^2+h^2}}}{2}$$

Note briefly
For optical purpose, an osculating ellipse should be used
$$\frac{x^2}{(R-h)^2}+\frac{y^2}{R(R-h)}=1$$

You need to choose another root for $b^2$, otherwise your $b>r$.

@IvanNeretin I've updated the sign inside the outer radical, which is checked that always within the lens graphically.

Good. Now it looks plausible, and also supports my earlier idea that there will be 4 tangency points, not 2. In other words, the ellipse will be less wide than the lens.
