Approximation of $\pi$ using an ellipse and a triangle
Here's how my approximation goes:
Take a point on the unit circle (in the first quadrant) and join it to the origin. Now, the area of the sector formed by the line and the x-axis is $\frac{\theta}{2}$. If you draw a perpendicular from the point on the circle to the x-axis, it divides the sector into a triangle and a fourth of a lens. The area of the triangle is $\frac{\sin\theta \cos\theta}{2}$. Now, I thought the lens looked a bit like an ellipse, so I asked this question. After I got my answer, I looked at the approximation, and it was horribly off. So, when I looked at the area between the lens and the ellipse (the top part), I thought it looked like a triangle. I added this in to get a better approximation, but it still didn't help much. Can anyone tell me what I can do to better the approximation?
Of course, the reason I'm not integrating is that it would bring that pesky radical sign, and then you have an infinite series, but all I'm looking for is a decently good approximation (preferably with known trigonometric ratios). Here is a desmos link that might help. (You will need to see the other answer for the context)
Edit: Here's another question related to this.

It helps to analyze the approximation quantitatively using orders of infinitesimals. For example, if we approximate the sector of area $\fracθ2$ using only the triangle of area $\frac{\sin θ \cos θ}{2}$, we get
\begin{align*}
π = \frac{2π}{θ} ⋅ \fracθ2 &≈ \frac{2π}{θ} ⋅ \frac{\sin θ \cos θ}{2} \\
&= \frac{2π}{θ} ⋅ \frac{(θ - \frac16θ^3 + o(θ^3))(1 - \frac12 θ^2 + o(θ^2))}{2} \\
&= π\left(1 - \frac23 θ^2 + o(θ^2)\right).
\end{align*}
Now if we add in some approximation for the remaining circular lens $\frac{θ - \sin θ \cos θ}{2}$ that’s off by a factor of $k$:
\begin{align*}
π = \frac{2π}{θ} ⋅ \fracθ2 &≈ \frac{2π}{θ} \left(\frac{\sin θ \cos θ}{2} + k\frac{θ - \sin θ \cos θ}{2}\right) \\
&= π\left(1 - (1 - k)\frac23 θ^2 + o(θ^2)\right).
\end{align*}
That is, as $θ → 0$, we will never be able to get better than second-order error unless the factor $k → 1$. This is the fundamental problem with your ellipse and triangle approximations: the ellipse only fills a fraction $k → \frac{π}{2√3} ≈ 0.907$ of the lens’s area, and the ellipse + triangle only fill a fraction $k → \frac{π}{2√3} + \frac{3 - \sqrt 6}{12} ≈ 0.953$.
A better approximation for the circular lens is a parabolic lens! The area of a parabolic lens is easily computed as exactly $\frac43$ times an inscribed triangle (as was known to Archimedes). Using this, we get
\begin{align*}
π &≈ \frac{2π}{θ} \left(\frac{\sin θ \cos θ}{2} + \frac43 ⋅ \frac{\sin θ (1 - \cos θ)}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{π}{3θ} \sin θ (4 - \cos θ) \\
&= \frac{π}{3θ} \left(θ - \frac16 θ^3 + \frac{1}{120} θ^5 + o(θ^5)\right) \left(3 + \frac12 θ^2 - \frac{1}{24} θ^4 + o(θ^4)\right) \\
&= π\left(1 - \frac{1}{30}θ^4 + o(θ^4)\right),
\end{align*}
which gives a much better fourth-order error.
Let’s put this to the test.

At $θ = \frac{π}{12}$, we have
\begin{align*}
  π &≈ 4\frac{\sqrt3 - 1}{2\sqrt2}\left(4 - \frac{\sqrt3 + 1}{2\sqrt2}\right) \\
  &= 4\sqrt6 - 4\sqrt2 - 1 ≈ 3.141105,
  \end{align*}
which is 0.016% away.

At $θ = \frac{π}{24}$, we have
\begin{align*}
  π &≈ 8\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}}{2}\left(4 - \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}}{2}\right) \\
  &= 16\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}} - \sqrt6 + \sqrt2 ≈ 3.141562,
  \end{align*}
which is just 0.00098% away, and better by about the expected factor of $2^4$.

At $θ = \frac{π}{48}$, we have
\begin{align*}
  π &≈ 16\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}}}{2}\left(4 - \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}}}{2}\right) \\
  &= 32\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}}} - 4 \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3}} ≈ 3.14159073,
  \end{align*}
which is just 0.000061% away, and better again by about $2^4$ times.



Are there other shapes, like the parabolic lens, which approximate the circular lens?

These approximations seem like Viete's formula and Liu Hui's approximations for pi. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula
